# Telegram InlineButton Callbackdata Problem

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I want when a user clicks an inline button, a message sent to another user!

Here is my code:

```
//creating inline keyboard
InlineKeyboardButton accept= new InlineKeyboardButton();
InlineKeyboardButton reject = new InlineKeyboardButton();
InlineKeyboardButton[] buttons = new InlineKeyboardButton[]
{
   accept, reject
};
InlineKeyboardMarkup inline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons);

//giving inline buttons text and callback data
accpet.Text = "accept";
reject.Text = "reject";
accept.CallbackData = "accept";
reject.CallbackData = "reject";

//instantiation "CallbackQuery" class
CallbackQuery callbackQuery = new CallbackQuery();

//send a text message to someone else if "callbackQuery.Data" was same a "accept" button callback data.
//This Part Doesn't Works. When I click accept button it does nothing!
if (callbackQuery.Data == "accept")
{
   await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatid,
                    "Hello World."
                    );
}
```

Thanks A lot For Your Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing wrong, You should wait until receiving `CallbackQuery` update, Not creating `new CallbackQuery();` And then try processing.

Telegram has something called *Updates*, Which means events when new message sent Or edited, Button pressed, User joined, etc.

So, You should create a `OnCallbackQuery` event, To handle any callback button pressed like this:

First, Creating the handler method:

```cs
botClient.OnCallbackQuery += botClient_OnCallbackQuery;

private void botClient_OnCallbackQuery(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs e)
{
    // Send the message to any one you want
    ChatId chatId = /*Put any chat ID you want*/;
    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Hello World.");
}
```

Second, You should handle any message via `OnMessage` event like this:

```
botClient.OnMessage += botClient_OnMessage;

private async void botClient_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    var message = e.Message;
    if (message.text == '/start')
    {
        var accept = InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Accept", "accept");
        var reject = InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Reject", "reject");
        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Accept Or Reject..", replyMarkup: new InlineKeyboardMarkup([accept, reject]));
    }
}
```